# Laravel Darkaonline/Swagger Validation Request Not Working

Tags: laravel, swagger, laravel-8

I am trying to create an API for the `sendOTP` function created in the controller. The package I'm using to do so is **[`DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger`](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger)** which generates swagger UI based on *OpenApi 3.0*. I am new to Laravel Swagger API and the problem is with validations. I have 2 fields that are supposed to be validated `country_code` & `mobile`. I pass the `$request` parameter to the LoginRequest to validate the data. Below are my controller and request code.

**LoginController**

```
/**
 * @OA\POST(
 *      path="/api/sendLoginOTP",
 *      operationId="sendLoginOTP",
 *      tags={"LoginviaOTP"},
 *      summary="Send Otp to mobile lstest",
 *      description="Sends Otp to Mobile and Returns mobile number and country code with default country code",
 *
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *          name="country_code",
 *          description="country code",
 *          required=true,
 *          in="path",
 *          @OA\Schema(
 *              type="string"
 *          )
 *      ),
 *     @OA\Parameter(
 *          name="mobile",
 *          description="mobile number",
 *          required=true,
 *          in="path",
 *          @OA\Schema(
 *              type="integer"
 *          )
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="successful operation"
 *       ),
 *      @OA\Response(response=400, description="Bad request"),
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=401,
 *          description="Unauthenticated",
 *      ),
 *      @OA\Response(response=404, description="Resource Not Found"),
 *      security={
 *         {
 *             "oauth2_security_example": {"write:projects", "read:projects"}
 *         }
 *     },
 * )
 */
public function sendOTP(LoginRequest $request)
{
    return response()->json('Validated');
}
```

**LoginRequest**

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'country_code' => [
            'required',
            'exists:countries,iso',
            'exists:users,country_code',
        ],
        'mobile' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
            'exists:users,mobile',
        ],
    ];
}
```

**Swagger UI**
[image: Swagger UI]

**Output I get After Entering Credentials**
[image: Output I get]

**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/fe6s9u4t/)** of whole output I am getting

**Output am expecting**
[image: expected output]

**My problem:** whenever I am trying to validate the parameters it's not getting validated. I am not sure where am I going wrong here. Am I not supposed to pass `$request` to `LoginRequest`? if not this method then how am I supposed to validate the data provided in the parameters?

Comment: Can you please share the proper error of output you're getting.

Comment: @Jayant Have added whole output code I'm getting in  https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/fe6s9u4t/ HTML section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the in value of parameters from `path` to `query` and it worked well for me

```
/**
  *     @OA\Parameter(
  *          ....
  *          in="query",
  *          ....
  *      ),
  *     @OA\Parameter(
  *          ....
  *          in="query",
  *          ....
  *      ),
  */
```